# asp.net core deployment on IIS - HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-8.5

I have a problem with my site up and running on windows server with IIS
On my local machine everything works fine with Visual Studio 2019.

Its a ASP.NET Core MVC Web Application. When I select publish to the local folder and upload everything to the server and create the website in IIS and try to run, I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
```

on the event viewer I have this error:

```
Application '/LM/W3SVC/12/ROOT' with physical root 'c:\Webs\mynetcoremvc\' failed to load coreclr. Exception message:
CLR worker thread exited prematurely
```

//note:
I have another ASP.NET Core API application running on the server without any problem. Both version 3.1.0

Comment: Could you please share your IIS web site's folder structure and details web.config setting?  Is the asp,net core application publish mode is self-contained or Farmework-depend? It seems that there is something wrong with the setting,

Answer (score 0):

Your startup.cs is throwing an error. Need to figure out what it is and it will solve that issue. Mine was due to KeyVault authorization issues.